# Dynamodb SDK v2 - how to map hashMap attribute field?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I have a dynamodb item UserOrders from previous implementation using SDK v1:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserOrders {

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    private String userId;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private HashMap<String, Double> orders;
}
```

I simply used @DynamoDBAttribute to map the orders field.

now i am migrating from SDK v1 to V2.

the UserOrders was changed to:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@DynamoDbBean
public class UserOrders {

    private String userId;

    private HashMap<String, Double> orders;

    @DynamoDbPartitionKey
    public String getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }
}
```

but when i fetch the items using enhanced client and .query() method, i get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Converter not found for EnhancedType(java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Double>)
```

how can i fix that?
should i create a dedicated convertor?